# Installing Angular CLI fails on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, npm, angular-cli

I am trying to install Angular my Ubuntu 16.04 system, but I get an error.

I tried to install the following way.

Versions:

```
myuser@mylaptop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
myuser@mylaptop:~$ node -v
v8.11.3
myuser@mylaptop:~$ npm -v
6.2.0
```

Installation:

```
myuser@mylaptop:~$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
[sudo] Passwort für myuser: 
/home/myuser/.npm-packages/bin/ng -> /home/myuser/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall /home/myuser/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/ng-update-message.js

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/myuser/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng-update-message.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall: `node ./bin/ng-update-message.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/myuser/.npm/_logs/2018-07-16T11_16_20_509Z-debug.log
```

Anyone having the same issue? Know how to solve this?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10728

Comment: @R.Richards Thanks for the link. This worked for me `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli --unsafe-perm=true`.

Comment: What is `unsafe-perm`? -> From https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config: Set to true to suppress the UID/GID switching when running package scripts. If set explicitly to false, then installing as a non-root user will fail.

Comment: I have always thought of that as a way to tell npm to ignore permissions, and just run the command.

Comment: @R.Richards Indeed sounds like the purpose of it. I regard towards this as a workaround.